# Passenger daily restarts nodejs app on CloudLinux

Tags: application-restart, passenger-apache

I have a nodejs application running on Apache server (Cloud Linux). The problem is that **Passenger restarts the nodejs app daily at midnight**, even if users are connected to the web application. I didn't find any cron asking to restart. Here is the Passenger log which is logged daily at midnight:

*Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 5519, application [...] (production)*

Is there a way to prevent this daily restart?

Or at least to change the restart time?

Comment: Hey, have you checked the folder 'tmp/sockets/' for a file called restart.txt or always_restart.txt? If one exists, remove it and the problem should go away.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Actually, I tried it but it does not work. I had a ./tmp/restart.txt file and another one ./restart.txt. I removed these 2 files, but Passenger still restarts the application at midnight...